# Is it possible to create an input with selectable text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I am using a asp.net webforms Button control. This is rendered as an html input element. I want to have a way for the user to be able to select the text inside the button, so that it can be copied and pasted elsewhere.

I can use either javascript, css, or c# to do this. I am not aware of any way to do this. is it possible?

```
<asp:button runat="server" id="btnSelectable" Text="MakeThisSelectable">
```

Edit: This appears to work easily for "button" elements, but not in firefox.
I am unable to select text for "input" elements, with a value set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Selectable text" CssClass="buttonStyle" />
```

and style it to look like a Button:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .buttonStyle
    {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can select the text on a button. It may be a bit different for asp .NET but I was able to select the text with this:

```
<button>selectable</button>
```

just click and hold outside the button and drag over the button.

Comment: Changed Title To remove the word button. I need my buttons to be part of the form, and cause a postback. This doesn't seem to work on input elements

Answer (score 0):

#### The Code

Here is a simple HTML element you can use:

```
<input type="text" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" value="YOUR TEXT HERE" readonly/>
```

#### How it works

*make the user unable to edit the text* - It is a text input, but the `readonly` at the end means that the text is not selectable.

*click to select* - this part works with the `onClick` attribute. When you click, it will set the `selectionRange` from index 0 (the first letter) to the last letter

*set the value* - set the value by setting the `value`